# Dropping layers in Transformer models (PyTorch / HuggingFace)

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I came across this interesting [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.03844.pdf) on layers dropping in Transformer models and I am actually trying to implement it. However, I am wondering what would be a good practice to perform "layer dropping".

I have have a couple of ideas but have no idea what would be the cleanest/safest way to go here:

- masking the unwanted layers (some sort of pruning)
- copying the wanted layers into a new model

If anyone has already done this before or has suggestion I'm all ears!

Cheers

Comment: I have also opened an issue on the official repo: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/14257#issue-1043175481

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think one of the safest ways would be simply to skip the given layers in the forward pass.

For example, suppose you are using `BERT` and that you added the following entry to the config:

```py
config.active_layers = [False, True] * 6  # using a 12 layers model
```

Then you could modify the `BertEncoder` class like the following:

```py
class BertEncoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__()
        self.config = config
        self.layer = nn.ModuleList([BertLayer(config) for _ in range(config.num_hidden_layers)])
        self.gradient_checkpointing = False

    def forward(
        self,
        hidden_states,
        attention_mask=None,
        head_mask=None,
        encoder_hidden_states=None,
        encoder_attention_mask=None,
        past_key_values=None,
        use_cache=None,
        output_attentions=False,
        output_hidden_states=False,
        return_dict=True,
    ):
        all_hidden_states = () if output_hidden_states else None
        all_self_attentions = () if output_attentions else None
        all_cross_attentions = () if output_attentions and self.config.add_cross_attention else None

        next_decoder_cache = () if use_cache else None
        for i, layer_module in enumerate(self.layer):
            
            ########### MAGIC HERE #############
            if not self.config.active_layers[i]:
                continue
            
            if output_hidden_states:
                all_hidden_states = all_hidden_states + (hidden_states,)

            layer_head_mask = head_mask[i] if head_mask is not None else None
            past_key_value = past_key_values[i] if past_key_values is not None else None

            if self.gradient_checkpointing and self.training:

                if use_cache:
                    logger.warning(
                        "`use_cache=True` is incompatible with gradient checkpointing. Setting `use_cache=False`..."
                    )
                    use_cache = False

                def create_custom_forward(module):
                    def custom_forward(*inputs):
                        return module(*inputs, past_key_value, output_attentions)

                    return custom_forward

                layer_outputs = torch.utils.checkpoint.checkpoint(
                    create_custom_forward(layer_module),
                    hidden_states,
                    attention_mask,
                    layer_head_mask,
                    encoder_hidden_states,
                    encoder_attention_mask,
                )
            else:
                layer_outputs = layer_module(
                    hidden_states,
                    attention_mask,
                    layer_head_mask,
                    encoder_hidden_states,
                    encoder_attention_mask,
                    past_key_value,
                    output_attentions,
                )

            hidden_states = layer_outputs[0]
            if use_cache:
                next_decoder_cache += (layer_outputs[-1],)
            if output_attentions:
                all_self_attentions = all_self_attentions + (layer_outputs[1],)
                if self.config.add_cross_attention:
                    all_cross_attentions = all_cross_attentions + (layer_outputs[2],)

        if output_hidden_states:
            all_hidden_states = all_hidden_states + (hidden_states,)

        if not return_dict:
            return tuple(
                v
                for v in [
                    hidden_states,
                    next_decoder_cache,
                    all_hidden_states,
                    all_self_attentions,
                    all_cross_attentions,
                ]
                if v is not None
            )
        return BaseModelOutputWithPastAndCrossAttentions(
            last_hidden_state=hidden_states,
            past_key_values=next_decoder_cache,
            hidden_states=all_hidden_states,
            attentions=all_self_attentions,
            cross_attentions=all_cross_attentions,
        )
```

At the moment you may need to write your special `BERT` class using the new `Encoder` layer. However, you should be able to load the weights from the pre-trained models provided by `huggingface`.

`BertEncoder` code taken from [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/68427c9bebd1e4ff43d25b18bb9c7eb786303712/src/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py#L528)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Luca, this looks pretty safe to me. I'll try that tomorrow and let you know ! :)

Comment: Hey @Luca, I actually got an answer from the HF guys and it seems that they are doing it similarly than what you suggested :) https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/c016dbdbdaf79339ae6d275d4651dc9f380be055/src/transformers/models/bart/modeling_bart.py#L795