# How to remove layers in Huggingface's transformers BERT pre-trained models?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, pre-trained-model

I'm currently trying to use a pretrained BertModel for finetuning. **How do I remove some of the layers from the model before fine-tuning?**

I've tried something like this:

```py
def deleteEncodingLayers(model, num_layers_to_keep):  # must pass in the full bert model
    oldModuleList = model.bert.encoder.layer
    newModuleList = nn.ModuleList()

    # Now iterate over all layers, only keepign only the relevant layers.
    for i in range(0, len(num_layers_to_keep)):
        newModuleList.append(oldModuleList[i])

    # create a copy of the model, modify it with the new list, and return
    copyOfModel = copy.deepcopy(model)
    copyOfModel.bert.encoder.layer = newModuleList

    return copyOfModel
```

**Is there a simpler way to remove the layers without going through the `ModuleList()`?**

Possibly this is similar to [Dropping layers in Transformer models (PyTorch / HuggingFace)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69835532/dropping-layers-in-transformer-models-pytorch-huggingface) but the answer to the question seems a little more complex than going through the `ModuleList()`.

There is also a pointer to https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.03844.pdf and https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/14257#issue-1043175481 but the lead there goes to models which supports layer-drops and not all pre-trained models support that feature https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/search?q=layerdrop.

Comment: OP c.f. https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/2483

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is looking for a way to remove layers for `EncoderDecoderModel` e.g. for [some models with unbalance layers](https://aclanthology.org/2020.amta-research.10/).

I've tried this, and it seems to work:

```py
from transformers import EncoderDecoderModel, BertLMHeadModel
from transformers import BertConfig, EncoderDecoderConfig, EncoderDecoderModel

# Initializing a BERT bert-base-uncased style configuration
config_encoder = BertConfig.from_pretrained("bert-base-multilingual-uncased")
config_decoder = BertConfig.from_pretrained("bert-base-multilingual-uncased")

config_encoder.num_hidden_layers = 5
config_decoder.num_hidden_layers = 2

config = EncoderDecoderConfig.from_encoder_decoder_configs(config_encoder, config_decoder)

# Initializing a Bert2Bert model from the bert-base-uncased style configurations
model = EncoderDecoderModel(config=config)

model.decoder # Shows 2 layers, if `num_hidden_layers` was unchanged, it should show 6.
```

[out]:

```
BertLMHeadModel(
  (bert): BertModel(
    (embeddings): BertEmbeddings(
      (word_embeddings): Embedding(105879, 768, padding_idx=0)
      (position_embeddings): Embedding(512, 768)
      (token_type_embeddings): Embedding(2, 768)
      (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
      (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
    )
    (encoder): BertEncoder(
      (layer): ModuleList(
        (0): BertLayer(
          (attention): BertAttention(
            (self): BertSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): BertSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (crossattention): BertAttention(
            (self): BertSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): BertSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
          )
          (output): BertOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (1): BertLayer(
          (attention): BertAttention(
            (self): BertSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): BertSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (crossattention): BertAttention(
            (self): BertSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): BertSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
          )
          (output): BertOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
  (cls): BertOnlyMLMHead(
    (predictions): BertLMPredictionHead(
      (transform): BertPredictionHeadTransform(
        (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
        (transform_act_fn): GELUActivation()
        (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
      )
      (decoder): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=105879, bias=True)
    )
  )
)
```

---

Similarly, if it's just an LM encoder model, something like this should work:

```py
from transformers import BertConfig, BertLMHeadModel

config_encoder = BertConfig.from_pretrained("bert-base-multilingual-uncased")
config_encoder.num_hidden_layers = 3
model = BertLMHeadModel(config=config_encoder)

model
```

[out]:

```
BertLMHeadModel(
  (bert): BertModel(
    (embeddings): BertEmbeddings(
      (word_embeddings): Embedding(105879, 768, padding_idx=0)
      (position_embeddings): Embedding(512, 768)
      (token_type_embeddings): Embedding(2, 768)
      (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
      (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
    )
    (encoder): BertEncoder(
      (layer): ModuleList(
        (0): BertLayer(
          (attention): BertAttention(
            (self): BertSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): BertSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
          )
          (output): BertOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (1): BertLayer(
          (attention): BertAttention(
            (self): BertSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): BertSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
          )
          (output): BertOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (2): BertLayer(
          (attention): BertAttention(
            (self): BertSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): BertSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
          )
          (output): BertOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
  (cls): BertOnlyMLMHead(
    (predictions): BertLMPredictionHead(
      (transform): BertPredictionHeadTransform(
        (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
        (transform_act_fn): GELUActivation()
        (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
      )
      (decoder): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=105879, bias=True)
    )
  )
)
```