# Hugging Face translation model cross attention layers problem, inconsistent with research

Tags: huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, text-alignment, attention-model, machine-translation

When I'm inspecting the cross-attention layers from the pretrained transformer translation model (MarianMT model), It is very strange that the cross attention from layer 0 and 1 provide best alignment between input and output. I used bertviz to visualize all heads from all 6 layers, and tried different language, english to german and english to chinese, it all gives the same results, which does not make sense because the last layers should be more accurate according to the paper *Jointly Learning to Align and Translate with Transformer Models* https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.02074.pdf

But when I'm looking at the cross attention of model *Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-en-de* and *Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-en-zh* , the layer 1 gives the best alignment. the code is below:

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel
import os
os.environ['TRANSFORMERS_CACHE'] = '/data2/hanyings/.cache'

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-en-de")
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-en-de", output_attentions=True)

encoder_input_ids = tokenizer("She sees the small elephant.", return_tensors="pt", add_special_tokens=True).input_ids
with tokenizer.as_target_tokenizer():
    decoder_input_ids = tokenizer("Sie sieht den kleinen Elefanten.", return_tensors="pt", add_special_tokens=True).input_ids

outputs = model(input_ids=encoder_input_ids, decoder_input_ids=decoder_input_ids)

encoder_text = tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(encoder_input_ids[0])
decoder_text = tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(decoder_input_ids[0])

from bertviz import model_view
model_view(
    encoder_attention=outputs.encoder_attentions,
    decoder_attention=outputs.decoder_attentions,
    cross_attention=outputs.cross_attentions,
    encoder_tokens= encoder_text,
    decoder_tokens = decoder_text
)
```

From the above pictures, I observed that the first 2 layers give the best alignment whereas the last layers do not align the input and output tokens properly. Can you please help me to explain why this happens? and If the alignment of the last layer is not accurate, how does the model provide correct predictions?  Please! It is very important for my research project!

I tried to read the source code of the MarianMT model to see if the layer0 is indeed the top layer(last layer), the order of cross attention layers is reversed. But I did not find anything. So Anyone can help? It is VERY IMPORTANT for my project!!!

Comment: Good insights, here's a tip: cut out all the other decoder layers beyond 2-layers and see what happens to the results. Reference: https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.04885 (table 3)

Comment: Theoretically, you might have thought having equal no. of encoder-decoders layer is good. But empirically from what you see in the bertviz and in results, very few decoder layers is needed to achieve SOTA results compared to equal encoder-decoder layers =) Alignment in attention isn't necessary to produce the right softmax/argmax tokens.

Comment: (Empirical) proof is in the pudding, here's some code to start with https://stackoverflow.com/a/74297958/610569 .  See also https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5080/empirical-results-in-cs-papers